# Hex to number algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, hex

Without using a python builtin, I'd like to write a basic routine to find the numeric value given a hex string. (In other words, I don't want to use `int('8c', 16)`) -- this is for learning purposes).

Here is what I have so far:

```
def hex_to_number(hex_string, num=0):
    number_map = {'0':0,'1':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'A': 10, 'B': 11, 'C': 12, 'D': 13, 'E': 14, 'F': 15}
    for char in hex_string:
        num = num << 4
        num += number_map[char]
    return num
```

Is it possible to to this conversion without the number map at the top or is that necessary to do the hex conversion? If not, how else might an algorithm (or even one-liner) be constructed to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ord(char)`. Quick example without validity check (for example, it is possible to add `a-f` treatment)

```
for char in hex_string:
    num = (num << 4) + (ord(char) - ord("0") if char < "A" else 10 + ord(char) - ord("A"))
```

Explanation:

Digit "0" has code 0x30 (48), other digits have the next codes in sequence, so to get numeric value of digit, we have to subtract "base" value. The same is true for "A"-"F" range (code of "A" is 0x41 (65)).

[ASCII table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html)

Another trick to treat also small letters (not an example of good code ;):

```
shifts = [48, 55, 87]
for char in hex_string:
    num = (num << 4) + (ord(char) - shifts[(ord(char) // 32) - 1])
```

`ord(char) // 32` gives results 1,2,3 for ranges of digits, large and small letters. Then we subtract corresponding base value (`shifts`)

Comment: that's pretty nifty -- could you explain a bit more how that works. For example, why do you subtract `ord('0')` ?

Comment: I added explanation into answer